# React-Native-Maps | Display Markers inside a Circle / inside my Radius?

Tags: react-native

i have problem with Maps & Markers.

I'm loading the markers from a GeoJson file. I only want to display the markers which are inside my current Position like 500m radius (In the Circle). Is this Possible? I dont want to load all the 700 markers bc of the performance. I hope you guys can help me.

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import Marker from 'react-native-maps';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
} from "react-native";

class Spielplaetze extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        markers: [],
        loaded: false
      }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.getLocations();
      this.getPosition();
    }

    getPosition(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
        console.log(position);
          this.setState({
            region: {
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              latitudeDelta:  0.020,
              longitudeDelta:  0.020,
            }
          });
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
       { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
     );
    }

    getLocations(){
    return fetch('http://media-panda.de/cologne.geojson')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData =>{
       var markers = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < responseData.features.length; i++) {
          if (responseData.features[i].properties.Torwand != '<Null>'){
            var coords = responseData.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
            var marker = {
              coordinate: {
                latitude: coords[1],
                longitude: coords[0],
              }
            }
            markers.push(marker);
          }
        }
        this.setState({
          markers: markers,
          loaded: true,
        });
      }
    ).done();
  }

  render() {

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView.Animated
        style={styles.map}
        region={this.state.region}
        showsUserLocation={true}
      >
       {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={marker.coordinate}
          />
       ))}
       </MapView.Animated>
      </View>
     );
  }
}

export default Spielplaetze;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  map: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show a sample of your GeoJson?

Comment: this is my code where I'm reading a GeoJson file with all my markers to display them out.

https://github.com/funkyyy/whsbpomemo/blob/master/screens/Spielplaetze.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great dependency called `geolib` that allows you to perform calculations such as distances between coordinates.

You can install it will `npm i geolib`. Using the `.getDistance` function that it provides you could filter the markers based on how far they are from your "center" point.

```
const geolib = require('geolib');

...

getLocations() {
  let { region } = this.state;
  let { latitude, longitude } = region;
  fetch('http://media-panda.de/cologne.geojson')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseData => {

    let markers = responseData.features.map(feature =>  {
      let coords = feature.geometry.coordinates
      return {
        coordinate: {
          latitude: coords[1],
          longitude: coords[0],
        }
      }
    }).filter(marker => {
      let distance = this.calculateDistance(latitude, longitude, marker.coordinate.latitude, marker.coordinate.longitude);
      return distance <= 500;
    });

    this.setState({
      markers: markers,
      loaded: true,
    });
  }).done(); // should probably have a catch on here otherwise you've got no way to handle your errors
}

// this function uses geolib to calculate the distance between the points
calculateDistance(origLat, origLon, markerLat, markerLon) {
  return geolib.getDistance(
    {latitude: origLat, longitude: origLon},
    {latitude: markerLat, longitude: markerLon}
  );
}
```

Basically what I am doing is mapping over the markers that are returned by your `fetch` request and turning them each into the following object

```
{ coordinate: { latitude: number, longitude: number } }
```

Then I am filtering them, using `geolib` to remove any that are further than 500m away from the center point.

Though one thing you should note is that in your current code setup you could get the GeoJson before you get the coordinates of the user's location. You may want to consider refactoring your `getLocations` and `getPosition` functions so that the `getLocations` will only run after the `getPosition` function has returned the region. Otherwise you won't be able to filter because the state value for `region` will not exist.

You may wish to call `getLocations` after you have gotten the region from `getPosition`, perhaps something like this, using the callback property of `setState`. That way the region will be in the state and you should be able to filter without any issues.

```
getPosition(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
    console.log(position);
      this.setState({
        region: {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta:  0.020,
          longitudeDelta:  0.020,
        }
      }, () => this.getLocations());
    },
    (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
    { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
  );
}
```

This is by no means the only way to do this. It really depends on your use case, but it should give you enough of an idea of what to do.

Comment: Wow Andrew you helped me a lot! thanks for the quick reply! I'll test it tomorrow. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: It worked very well I'm very new in react native. Iam so thankful for you 

`.filter(marker => {
      let distance = this.calculateDistance(latitude, longitude, marker.coordinate.latitude, marker.coordinate.longitude);
      return distance <= 500;`

i would never have solved that.

we hard coded here the 500m radius - what about a slide bar where user can slide the radius? is this tricky? i saw this one 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-range-slider

is it easy to modify?

Comment: That's great that it worked, if my answer helped you please mark it as the accepted answer. With regard to your slider question, that should be fairly easy to implement (though I have never used that [component myself](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-range-slider)). You should give it a go and if you get stuck post another question. Personally I would start simple, perhaps with a `TextInput` and get all the logic working for the range changing and then try to implement a slider.

Comment: you are right, i should first go the easy way with a text input :D

how can i mark it for a accepted answer?

in my app there are 2 warnings can I ignore them?

1 Warning is - Failed Prop type - The Prop 'Center' is marked as required in MapCircle, but its value is undefined.

But I defined it with center = { this.state.region },  i got my circle in my currentlocation but why iam getting a warning :D?

and the 2nd warning is

Each Child in an Array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

i dont understand this warnung :/

Comment: I would suggest posting another question with the code related to MapCircle as there is no MapCircle in the above code. Comments are only really for asking for clarification not for asking new questions.

Comment: Hey Andrew i hope you can help me a bit. As we know everything works fine with iOS but if iam starting the app with any Android devices iam Getting an error with null references i dont know what to do.  Look at Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYtkT.jpg

Comment: You should post a new question. That way you can add all the error messages and code relevant to the problem.

Comment: i already post a new question but noone helps me out :/ i thought maybe you could help me  i posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141383/react-native-null-reference-maps-markers-android

Comment: I can't fetch data from this API. Can you give me an updated API URL?

Comment: @MuflahNasir  I don't have any example URL you can use. You would have to ask the original question poster if they have an updated link as I used their API URL in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I found the URL later from his next issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this question helped me a lot. One thing to note though: there is a typo in the answer.

The code should be:

```
coordinate: {
  latitude: coords.latitude,
  longitude: coords.longitude,
}
```

And not:

```
coordinate: {
  latitude: coords[1],
  longitude: coords[0],
}
```

I hope that this will help others as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29779697)