# How can I display description of a marker on the map with Reactnative

Tags: react-native

Hey guys I'm stucking on my code.

I'm able to display mulitple markers from a geojson file.
but I dont know how to clickable the markers to get the description which is set in the geojson file.

this is how I'm getting the coordinations but I don't have a clue how to fetch some important informations of this location.

```
getLocations() {
    return fetch('http://media-panda.de/bp/whs.geojson')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
      let { region } = this.state;
      let { latitude, longitude } = region;

      let markers = responseData.features.map(feature =>  {
      let coords = feature.geometry.coordinates
        return {
          coordinate: {
            latitude: coords[1],
            longitude: coords[0],
          }
        }
      }).filter(marker => {
          let distance = this.calculateDistance(latitude, longitude, marker.coordinate.latitude, marker.coordinate.longitude);
          return distance <= this.state.value;
        });
      this.setState({
        markers: markers,
        loaded: true,
        });
    }).done();
 }
```

and my view is like:

```
<MapView.Animated
            style={styles.map}
            region={this.state.region}
            showsUserLocation={true}
          >
          {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
            <MapView.Marker
              key={Math.random()}
              coordinate={marker.coordinate}
              description={marker.description}
            />
            ))}
            <MapView.Circle
              center= {this.state.region}
              radius = { this.state.value }
              strokeWidth = { 1 }
              strokeColor = { '#1a66ff' }
              fillColor = { 'rgba(230,238,255,0.5)' }
            />
</MapView.Animated>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see your problem now, you are trying to set description outside of the getLocation function but you are still trying to use responseData which only exists inside of the getLocations function.
You are already mapping over each item in the responseData array, just add the title and description here.

You can easily do it inside the function you already have;

```
let markers = responseData.features.map(feature =>  {
      let coords = feature.geometry.coordinates
      let name = feature.properties.Name
      let description = feature.properties.description
        return {
          coordinate: {
            latitude: coords[1],
            longitude: coords[0],
          },
          title: name,
          description: description
        }
      })
```

Comment: as you can see i already added the description prop but it'n not working :/ i think it cant handle out because i'm taking to informations of the marker from a geojson file

Comment: I see in getLocations where you are setting marker.coordinates, but I do not see where you are setting marker.description?

Comment: thats my problem i tried to set it but i think I do it wrong.

I tried it with:

let desc = responseData.features.map(feature =>  {
      let description = feature.properties
        return {
          description: this.description
        }
      }


or do i have to create a new method like getDescription() ?

Comment: @Mehmet, does the above fix your problem?

Comment: hey @SHG21 i already solve it, but i didnt saw your post. I got it the same way :D thanks anyway :)